# Why does PHP's $_POST variable get values from HTML's name attribute instead of id attribute?

Tags: php, html

I understand that when accessing values of HTML form elements in PHP, we must use the `name` attribute within the `$_POST` variable. However, I'm not sure I understand ***why*** that's the case. It seems to me like it may have been better for `$_POST` to use `id` attributes and take advantage of the insured uniqueness, rather than potentially finding multiple values if more than 1 form elements share the same `name`. I'm sure there's a good reason why `name` attributes are used instead of `id`, but I haven't been able to dig that up and curious to understand why.

Simple example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <form action="./some_script.php" method="post">
        <input type='text' id='text_input_id' name ='text_input_name'>
        <input type='submit'>
    </form>
</html>
```

**some_script.php**

```
<?php
    $value_from_id = $_POST["text_input_id"]; // will be null
    $value_from_name = $_POST["text_input_name"]; // will contain text input from form
?>
```

Comment: `id`s are unique across the page, yes, but `name`s don't have to be unique.  You can even send multiple values under the same `name` using `[]`.  Like `name="yourArray[]"`, if you add this to multiple fields, then you will get an array in `$_POST['yourArray']`.

Comment: Here's the docs for the `name` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary reason is that forms were added to HTML before IDs were.

However, an ID must be unique in an HTML document but a name doesn't. You can have multiple form controls with the same name.

Sometimes this is required e.g. in order to create a radio group:

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="availability" value="yes" id="availability_yes">
  <label for="availability_yes">Yes</label>

  <input type="radio" name="availability" value="no" id="availability_no">
  <label for="availability_no">No</label>

  <input type="radio" name="availability" value="if need be" id="availability_inb">
  <label for="availability_inb">If Need Be</label>
</form>
```

and sometimes it is just useful (e.g. when picking from a list of things).

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Acceptable Colours</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" value="red" id="colours_red">
    <label for="colours_red">Red</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" value="green" id="colours_green">
    <label for="colours_green">Green</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" value="blue" id="colours_blue">
    <label for="colours_blue">Blue</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: In the checkbox group, wouldn't you want `name="colours[]"`?

Comment: Oh  yes, I forgot about that PHP oddity. (Normally no, but the question was PHP focused).